# failed linking references resource and duplicate value after update Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I've been researching this issue for the past 5 days. And there were enough solutions, but no one could help me. Please tell me a solution to this problem.

Some Screenshots and Code Here Below:

> Screenshots:-[Click Here to See Image Problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LZzE.png)
>
> Screenshots:-[Click Here to See Image Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMKYp.png)
>
> Screenshots:-[Click Here to See Image Problem 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haQ27.png)

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ummat.anmolmessages"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Quotes" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.All_Inflater_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.Latest_QuoteList_Fragment"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.Favorite_Fragment"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.AuthorList_Fragment"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.AuthorQuoteList_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.Albert_Inflater_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.Setting_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.AboutActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.CategoryList_Fragment"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ummat.anmolmessages.CategoryQuoteList_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle (Module App)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.ummat.anmolmessages"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 29
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    }

Build.gradle (Project Module)





    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
 #Mon Sep 09 15:19:17 PKT 2019
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: You can't use actionbarsherlock and appcompat libraries together. But no reason to use actionbarsherlock nowdays.

Comment: It seems you had some issues with your images as links, can you edit your question to put them back?

Comment: Now Check Images

Comment: Gabriele Mariotti: Dear, I have migrate this project from Eclipse, this issue has been coming ever since.Now tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** use appcompat and actionbarsherlock together.
Just use appcompat, it is enough.

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

Comment: I have removed the action bar. But then there is the problem with the Activity where it has been used.

Comment: @AbdulRehman You have to use AppCompatActivity. In any case this is a separate problem.It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question, with all details.